# PHP Session not written after Output(echo or print_r on external ajax Call)

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I´m having some serious trouble debugging this particular problem and I hope someone has a clue what i´m doing wrong.

I have a Custom CMS system working that uses Paragraphs as building blocks that get updated using Ajax(prototypejs) calls and functions that parse the HTML chunks in given order, clean them up and save this data in associative arrays in a Session variable.
Users log in, Session is created and I can check for this session without problem in every page I need it. The system works directly on the definitive websites, so the user can see his updates on realtime and browse the site as a normal user would do, but editing.
So, nothing new here. But here is the weird thing.

**Enduser site on edit mode(admin user logged in): path "/"**

After the logged status is verified, a function processes the editable content and saves an associative array to session, it also starts some javascript objects for editing every paragraph. Data is actually saved, I can use an external script to check if it´s there after this php script ends.If I load a new page(new content), Session gets updated with new data)

Admin User modifies a paragraph using an Inplaceeditor and this HTML chunk is send via Ajax to a php script that starts the named session, reads the present session data, checks if a paragraph should be modified, appended or deleted and reassigns values to existing array keys in `$_SESSION`. if i make a `var_dump()` o print_r to `$_SESSION` after assigning new data is there.After that the script echoes the processed html, and ajax updates the original paragraph on the calling page.

This script is in /admin/cms/...etc, that means at least 4 directories inside the root of the site.

When the script ends, I check using the same session dump script to see if data was really written/commited, but no, `$_SESSION` has only the original data from the calling page.
Same ID, same session name, same `session_start()` but no data gets written.
This whole operation is very quick, so I though it could be a speed problem, scripts ends before session_write_close can make his work.

But if I add a new  key to `$_SESSION` array and put some data there, data gets updated and written. If i don´t output anything on this script and just process data and set session variables it also get´s updated and written.

It´s like some members of `$_SESSION` array are getting blocked to update.

**What i did to track this error and what i´m sure i´m not doing wrong.**

- 1.- `register_globals` are off of course
- 2.- `session_name()` and `session_start()` are always present and in the given
  order. I used to have multiple
  `session_start()` -close on a same page
  to use several named sessions, but to
  refine the problem this is not longer
  so.
- 3.- I use `session_write_close()` after session data is processed. Also
  tried    without, letting php decide 
  when to    commit data, but no luck.
- 4.- I`m using only cookies for SID.
- 5.- sessions are stored on /tmp, i can see the data getting updated.
- I also tried using a custom save
  handler on DB, but same problem,
  "_write" got only called when no output as present.
- I searched php.net, stackoverflow, google, etc for this subject. I never ask without investigation, this is my first time in many years...but it´s just so unlogical it must be something tiny a haven´t thought of.

The most weird thing is that when I just process data without output `$_SESSION` gets updated ok. But if i modify this script afterwards by adding the output  and try again, instead of just having  the new(last) value present I get the original value back, the one created by the calling page at first place, sometimes after playing around a few times! PHP can´t cache values between scripts or?I dont have globlals on.

I´m really clueless. This system worked flawless on PHP4.3, since i´m using 5.3.3 for two moths my users where caliming data where getting mixed up, so i checked and yes, there are serious problems. Today I updated to (5.3.6) and I can´t get this session values commited.

Script code called via Ajax:

```
<?
session_cache_limiter('nocache'); 
session_name("CMS_ses");
session_start();
include('../htmLawed/htmLawed.php');
include("utils_cms.php");
include("../../../php/utils_array.php");

$value=$_POST['value'];
$editorId=$_POST['editorId'];
$clase=$_POST['clase'];
$editorId=str_replace("pre","",$editorId);
$value=html_entity_decode(stripslashes($value),ENT_QUOTES);
if (strlen(trim($value))==0)
    {
    die();
    }
$value="<div id=\"$editorId\"  class=\"$clase\">$value</div>";

$newXHTML=$value;
$retorno=CMS_nuevoBloque($newXHTML,$editorId);
$_SESSION['data']['CMSeditores']=$retorno[1];   
$_SESSION['data']['CMScont']=$retorno[2];   
session_write_close();

print_r($retorno[0]); //Offending part...without everything works
?>
```

really nothing strange here....main page code is even simpler, no strange php directives, etc.

Here is the header of the caller page

```
include 'php/db.php';
$len=$_GET['len'];
$sec=$_GET['sec'];
$cont=$_GET['cont'];
$admfin=$_GET['admfin'];
$fecha=$_GET['fecha'];
$token=$_GET['token'];
$cur=$_GET['cur'];

$PHP_SELF=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
session_name("CMS_ses");
session_start();

$passvar='';
unset($adm);
if ((!empty($_SESSION['cms_logged'])) and (!isset($admfin)) )
    {
    $nivelpermisos=$_SESSION['cms_logged_group'];
    $useractual=$_SESSION['cms_logged'];
    $adm=1;

    }
elseif (empty($_SESSION['cms_logged']))
    {
    unset($useractual);
    }
    //.........rest of the code
```

UPDATE: I did late night tests and found someting i don´t understand.HElP please:
It has not only to do with Sessions but also with Mysql Querys. Same code, but instead of trying to write to `$_SESSION` array i made a simple update to a Innodb table using the session_id. When i Output some code, the update does get executed,(i can output the query string and no `mysql_error()` or notice) problems, but checking the database the row doesn´t get updated. Letting the output out if the script and Query does get commited. Only common thing is sessions are started and output is made.

I restarted Apache, etc(who knows) but no luck. Then i made something really stupid, because this is a server side thing. I changed my browser to Firefox(using  safari) and everything works! Ok, recheck, back to safari, nothing works. Both running side by side, same issue. PHP is server side, how can different browsers handle code different, can a browser say to apache rollback, request not handled or call the same script twice without notice(checked safaris developer console and the script is called only once) ? Can safari resubmit data silently because it "thinks" ajax failed? I checked headers using firebug and Safaris developer tools , nothing strange but whenever i make a Ajax call with safari, the caller page reloads data(Aka conection to server...).

I really don´t understand nothing.

Comment: @_@ This made my eyes go all googly.

Comment: Ok, it´s getting even Stranger, i really need some help Here:

Comment: Very hard question. If anything, this is worth extra points. Whos up for it?

Comment: error_reporting set to E_ALL, display_errors to "1"? If not, do it. It may be some headers issue. Also, when using MySQL to store sessions, do you commit transaction and no errors happens before commit?

Comment: 2 Questions - 1. Does anything in php/db.php manipulate the session? 2. Are you doing any header redirects on your code?  I was having a session problem and it was because I wasn't exiting after all my header redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this (if I have understood correctly). I needed to force session data to be written (for a custom session driver) after scripts have finished running. A shutdown function can be registered which should run after scripts have finished.

Maybe this will solve (or help you to solve) your problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: Not the perfect answer, but at least you offered a specific solution and didn't ask any questions. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

Thank's for your help. I was doing everything in the right order and still session data was not being written. Session names where necesary because sometimes we test many sites on the same domain using the same custom CMS. So, finally, after making lots of test and no luck, i found that register globals was active on this server(we never use it, code was written having this option off in mind of course), but it messes with sessions!. Switching this off made a huge change. No more problemas. I also made a custom session handler in DB, so i could track the problems in an more centralized way.
Conclussion: Never use register globals + named sessions, an complex data in sessions. 
Anyway, i will give this issue more time and more tests. Ajax calls are also sometimes too fast, i had to put a sleep command so writing the session data was really done.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but it was having with ie few years back. IE manipulates the header on its own way and that causes strange php bugs that you can find in php.net archives.

@Diego Pino Navarro, please see [this help page](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php) and find Safari and it's issues with php.

I also found ["Safari "forget" http-authentication's logon-information"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1674538?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but few suggestion i think may be helpful.

delete session cookies before refreshing the page for testing purposes :)

Ensure that you're not assigning any arrays with a key containing the pipe character (|). This will prevent the session data from being serialized and saved.

Do session_regenerate_id(true); many cases session_write_close doesn't seem to matter with out session_regenerate_id. or just do session_start() after session_write_close() if you are relying on SID ; and in your case i think this is what is causing problem to you as you are ending the current session every time and not re starting it for the next page. hope u get my point. Further more To Make sure data is actually flushed out to the browser use ob_end_flush();

i could not understand the connection between

```
$_SESSION['data']['CMSeditores']=$retorno[1];   
$_SESSION['data']['CMScont']=$retorno[2];
```

and

```
$nivelpermisos=$_SESSION['cms_logged_group'];
    $useractual=$_SESSION['cms_logged'];
```

i think you need to paste some more code where the data part is causing problem instead of admin login part.

i hope this helps you.:)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're establishing the session name twice? I've had issues in the past where I would establish the session without a name, then another piece of script (not mine) was naming the session. Even at the end of the script I was able to print out the session variable, but once I went to a new page my session had been forgotten. It wasn't until I copied the name included in the 2nd script into my session call that it was solved.

Check that there's no other session names being used; also, maybe try only naming the session once, at the first call to the session?

Answer (score 0):

Question: Are you calling session_start() first thing... before ANY output to the browser and before any variables are assigned?

Sounds silly but give it a try.

Also, why are you using session names? Really not necessary unless you have a lot of session variables with the same name serving different purposes and if thats the case then you need to fix that first!